# How to change environment's font size?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the environment font size in Visual Studio Code? Stuff like IntelliSense box, debug panel, file names, etc.

I know how to change the editor's font size but I cannot figure out how to change the environment font size. So I wonder if you can change it somehow.

Comment: All these answers also change the editor font size.  How can I change the environment font size without the editor?

Comment: Surprising how much non answers get up voted. An answer to the OP question is just not be found here. Yet so many repeat the same answer to the exact same, yet different question from the OP.

Comment: Astonishing the number of posts that aren't answering the actual question but how to change the font size

Comment: Use CTRL+ and CTRL- to zoom the IDE, you dont have to look for the setting... for whoever reads this after reading the answer below...

Comment: User Arleme finally posted correct approach to solving the problem on July 16, 2021. You have to manually tinker with `c:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css` file. Looks like different sections of vscode have their font-size defined in different places. Also, increasing the font-size does not increase padding or line height, so merely increasing font-size is not enough. MS needs to develop a setting for this.

Comment: [Link to the best, most correct answer of all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-environments-font-size#answer-68405296) by Arleme.

Comment: I just looked into increasing size of filenames. Line height for each file is defined in-line in "style" attribute. As far as I can tell it is (close to) impossible to achieve what OP as asking. It will require developers baking this feature into vscode or maybe an extension. Not sure if extension can do something like that, though.

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to change the font family or size outside the editor. You can however zoom the entire user interface in and out from the `View` menu.

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

A newly introduced setting `window.zoomLevel` allows to persist the zoom level for good! It can have both negative and positive values to zoom in or out.

Comment: if you zoom out and wonder why the cursor is disappearing, check if you have it set to "thin line". Setting it to "line" will correct the problem, at least for down to 60% zoom.

Comment: Window zoom has a downside, it can trigger "fuzzy fonts" in terminal for instance:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84194

Comment: Use CTRL+ and CTRL- to zoom the IDE, you dont have to look for the setting...

Comment: It works. But it won't change the font size in the drop down menus. That is set by the operation system (at least on Mac OS X).

Answer (score 263):

In Visual Studio Code, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> you can change the overall font size of the IDE.
This helps faster than changing settings in every session.

Comment: note, this modifies user settings     "window.zoomLevel": 1,

Comment: In the most recent version, zoom in is  ```Ctrl + =```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 240):

Just copy `"editor.fontSize": 18` into your `setting.json` of the editor.

Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then typing "settings" will allow you to easily find the user or workspace settings file.

[image]

Comment: This work well, but not the same as OP want, to resize whole things not only in text editor

Comment: @StepanSuvorov see my new answer below, i know it comes late though, cheers!

Comment: @randomguy04 still don't see shortcut for changing size in your answer

Comment: this worked for me, I wanted to increase the font size of the open file only, not the sidebar, so I did the above and set increase font size to a defined hotkey.

Answer (score 109):

Try playing around with a combination of the following user settings:

```
{
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1.5,
}
```

Comment: `"window.zoomLevel": 1.5` is a very good choice for old guy like me

Comment: If you want the text smaller choose a negative number: `"window.zoomLevel": -0.5`

Comment: +1. Using keyboard shortcuts modifies this value by 1 (integer). Didn't know it could be set to decimals/floats.

Answer (score 21):

**As of mid 2017** To quickly get to the settings files press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and enter `settings`, there you will find the user settings and the workspace settings, be aware that **the workspace settings will override the user settings**, so it's better to use the latter directly to make it a global change (workspace settings will create a folder in your project root), from there you will have the option to add the option `"editor.fontSize": 14` to your settings as a quick suggestion, but you can do it yourself and change the value to your preferred font size.

To sum it up:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
2. select "user settings"
3. add `"editor.fontSize": 14`

Comment: this does NOT answer OP's question. OP specifically asks for changing environment font size, not editor font.

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback @Chris, however I do think it answers the question and has the necessary information. if you want it to have it per environment, change the workspace settings rather than the user settings and, your specifi env settings will be persisted in the `.vscode` folder

Comment: The OP asks for the `environment`, as in everything in the GUI that is not in the text editor, `Stuff like IntelliSense box, debug panel, file names, etc`. I could be wrong, but I don't think OP refers to the env that you are talking about

Answer (score 21):

You can **Zoom In and Zoom Out** the entire user interface from the View menu.

Right now i'm using *version 1.21.1* and there in **view menu** you can get the Zoom in and Zoom out option which are the 2nd and 3rd last options.
You can do it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

You can reset the zoom at any time by selecting **Reset Zoom** option.

Comment: Here the entire user interface means the VSCode editor.

Comment: Yeah, that scales the entire window, which is perfect if you have a high resolution screen

Answer (score 17):

After Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> as suggested by @Edwin:

1. Look for Workspace Settings:

[image]

2. Then "Place your settings in the file to the right to overwrite...default and user settings," or click the UserSettings tab to adjust the window.zoomLevel if that is the desired action.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

According to the changelog of version 1.2, new commands were added to zoom in and out only the font but the entire UI.

Changelog: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_font-zoom-commands

Use the following keybindings to replace the default global zoom actions:

on macOS:

```
{ "key": "cmd+numpad_add",      "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "shift+cmd+=",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "cmd+=",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "cmd+numpad_subtract", "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "shift+cmd+-",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "cmd+-",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "cmd+numpad0",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
{ "key": "cmd+0",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
```

on Windows and Linux:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad_add",      "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "shift+ctrl+=",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+=",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad_subtract", "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "shift+ctrl+-",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "ctrl+-",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad0",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
{ "key": "ctrl+0",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
```

Comment: Try this:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P ->
2. Search for (Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts) ->
3. At the top right end of Keyboard Shortcuts [Tab], Next to the Split Editor Button there is the Open Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON) button to open keybindings.json file ->
4.  Paste the above commands in that keybinding.json file and save ->
5. Now test the above key combinations to change the just only font size in VS code without changing the UI size

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio Code, the font-size can be easily changed from the Settings tab.

The *simplest* way to do this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then type 'Settings'. This will show you a few results. Choose 'Settings(UI)'. The Settings tab will get opened in the editor. Now you can change the font settings from here. This will only affect the editor's font.

Or, you can also click on the settings icon on the left bottom of the window and search for font from there.

[image]

In order to change the font size of the entire environment, you may consider pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. This will work like zooming into the whole environment, resulting in an increased font-size.

[image: Select Settings(UI)]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 11):

(VS Code 1.33.1 on Windows 7)

Zoom all (UI and editor): CTRL + **+**, CTRL + **-**.

Zoom editor: CTRL + Mouse Wheel.

See below how i fixed it.

As suggested by @Edwin: Pressing Control+Shift+P and then typing "settings" will allow you to easily find the user or workspace settings file.

My settings file is found here: "C:\Users\You_user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json"

My file looks like this:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.suggestFontSize": 6,
    "markdown.preview.fontSize": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and go to **`Settings -> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) -> settings.json`**
Copy and paste the following code lines:

```
"editor.fontSize": 15,
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
```

Save and close the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> this will get your work done. You can also experiment it by changing those values.

Comment: −1 This answer does a better job explaining how to copy-paste code than it does explaining what that code actually does.

Answer (score 8):

A Simple approach to change the Font Size in Visual Studio Work Environment :

**Go To** : File -> Preferences -> Settings **OR** Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> i.e. CTRL + COMMA.

This will open **settings.json**.

You can see 3 tabs there :

1. User Settings
2. Workspace Settings
3. Folder Settings

Go to **User Settings** and Add this :

```
{
"editor.fontSize": 16
}
```

Now just **save and close** the file.

In above code, **16** represents the font size. Increase of Decrease as per your wish.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Comment: @mcmuffin6o: While I sincerely appreciate your effort to clean up the site—and especially on these questions with a _lot_ of answers!—you’ll likely find that your flags are rejected when someone makes a sincere effort to answer their understanding of the question, even if they misunderstood the question. (This is a lesson I learned the hard way.) You could _try_ a custom flag for a moderator to explain why they’re not relevant, but even that’s unlikely to get through except in the most overt cases.

Comment: @mcmuffin6o: Generally, the “Not an Answer” flag is literally for answers that make no attempt to answer the question—e.g., follow-up questions, comments on other answers, or links to answers without any details in the post itself.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I see. Thanks for the tip! One particularly unfortunate pattern I noticed is newer answers that copy-paste old answers while tweaking some small detail. There are a large group of such answers on this post, each with a suspiciously similar number of upvotes. Perhaps we should be able to mark answers as duplicates, just as we would questions? I don't think it's too high of an expectation that answerers glance through the existing solutions before dumping the same 3-5 sentence answer that there are already a dozen copies of. This comment has become something that should be on meta..

Comment: @mcmuffin6o: Yeah, that gets to me too, and I’d love to see a flag for duplicate answers, which allows you to select which answer it’s a duplicate of. That said, I frequently flag duplicates for moderator attention and they’re quite receptive to removing those posts—though custom flags can take a while to get processed. Thank you for your diligence in helping keep the content focused and relevant.

Answer (score 8):

Took me ages to work out what I'd accidentally done when my code window went huge:

**Zoom out** = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma)

**Zoom in** = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (full stop/period)

Not actually an answer to the posted question at all but I think someone like me will end up here because of the symptoms!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

I have mine set to `"editor.fontSize": 12,`

Save the file, you will see the effect right the way.

[image]

**Enjoy !**

Comment: that's not what was asked for

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 6):

As of now (March 2018) & version 1.21.0, you can go to Settings, search for 'zoom' and change `"editor.mouseWheelZoom": false` which is false by default to `true`. This will allow to zoom in/out on VS Code using control button and mouse - `ctrl + scrollUp/scrollDown`. For changing the `fontSize` of the overall working space/screen of VS Code, refer to Alegozalves's answer above.

Comment: This answer is even more irrelevant than the rest.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> at the same time, a menu will appear, search for `Editor Zoom in`.
After selecting that, the font will get larger by some degree.

Repeat this until you achieve your desired font size.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 5):

There are many options to change the font size in the Visual studio code(version:1.36.1), Editor

## Option 1:

Go To: **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** > select **User** tab > **Text Editor** > **Font** > **Font Size**

***Font Size:*** Change font size in pixels as per your requirement

---

## Option 2:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Search: **settings.json**, Open file and add this line in  **settings.json** file:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 20
}
```

Note: Save file after changes

---

## Option 3:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Search: **Editor Font Zoom In**

- Just click on it, your font size will be ***increased***

Search: **Editor Font Zoom Out**

- Just click on it, your font size will be ***decreased***

Comment: this is the fifth answer that does not answer the question in the same way

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 5):

**FOR MAC**

command with +
command with -

**FOR WINDOWS**

control with +
control with -

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to change the environment's font, edit the css in

```
c:/Users/etech/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css
```

Just put at the end of the file your custom CSS :

```
body{
   font-size : 15px !important
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to correct answer. You **have to** tinker with `workbench.desktop.main.css` file to increase environment font.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting window.zoom that can enlarge the entire window content including the top menus and side nav tree.  Setting this to 1 on a 4k monitor makes the content similar to a 1080p monitor of the same physical size.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, in 2022 I will use,

<kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> + <kbd>**+**</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> + <kbd>**-**</kbd> to zoom out the environment.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. OP asked if there was a way to change the "_environment_ font size" (emphasis mine), **NOT** the editor font size. He specifically stated "I know how to change the editor's font size".

Answer (score 1):

I realize this response is very "late in the game", but I think I have a solution that actually addresses the OP's original question on how to increase the font of the menus. It would appear that VSCode sets its Menu font size based on the operating system.  The "fix" I am about to describe will change the font size of ALL apps, not just VSCode so use accordingly.  This is Windows specific, but there may be corresponding setting(s) for Linux and Mac.  Press the Windows key and search for Settings, from there search for Ease of Access display settings.  From there use the slider to "Make Text Bigger" and then click Apply.  This will take several seconds to Apply and all screens will be blue while the change is taking affect.  [image: Look Here]

Comment: I like the thinking here, but I ended up on this post specifically because VS Code does not respect Linux's "large text" accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the font size of your code without increasing the entire editor.. you can enable editor.mousewheelzoom
[image]

Now hold CTRL and mouse wheel to zoom-out or zoom-in

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the mouse wheel to **zoom In** or **Out**.

Comment: You can Zoom In and Zoom Out the entire user interface from the View menu. But question is how to change font size

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VS Code
2. Type command **CTRL + SHFT + P**
3. Type **Settings**
4. Settings file will open.
5. Now under User > Text Editor > Font, find **Font Size**
6. Enter your desired font size

That's it.

Comment: This is not what the question was about. It was about the environment font (menus etc), not the text editor font.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. You're telling us how to configure editor font size, not the environment/shell font size.

Answer (score -4):

File --> Preferences --> Settings --> User --> Font --> Font Size
Enter the Font size.
You can sync these settings with your Git Hub or Microsoft TFS.

[image]

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Please re-read the question. The question is asking about changing the font size for the *whole environment*, not just the editor (where they also say they already know how to change the editor font size), and the latter has already been covered in multiple previous answers.