# How to change the font of the variables in the Debug sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Do to my screen size I use the following to render all code in the editor - specifically using bold.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "monospace",
"editor.fontWeight": "bold",
"editor.fontSize": 14,
```

When debugging, the variables in the debug sidebar are rendered in some sort of monospace font in normal weight. I find the variables font incredibly hard to read. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-visual-studio-code-environment-font-size

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

In my case, the debug sidebar is rendered with font **Courier New**, which has very thin strokes. I ended up disabling this font on my system using font manager as suggested by [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371213/how-to-delete-fonts-in-ubuntu).

After disabling this font and restarting VS Code, the debug sidebar is now rendered with another mono font that looks much better (in my case **Roboto Mono**).