# How do I make the Code bigger in Visual Studios?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Warning: Total Newbie
I'm learning VB in Visual Studios and I want to make the code in the .vb tab to be bigger so it's easier to read. I know there's a way to do it, but I just can't remember.

Comment: Hold Ctrl and scroll the mouse to zoom in. To make the change more permanent, click `Tools` >> `Options` >> `Environment` >>  `Fonts and Colors`, and change the font size there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change environment's font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-environments-font-size)

Answer (score 7):

Hold Ctrl key and use your mouse scroll ball. Alternatively, in the lower left there is a percentage value, change it.

Answer (score 1):

Faster keyboard option is Ctrl key and + or - (on the num side of the keyboard) to zoom in/out in almost any new program these days.