# Change the number of lines shown in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to change the number of lines displayed in VS Code. Any idea how can I do that?

[image: Here is the picture]

As you can see ,it can show 17 lines of code. How can I change that?

Comment: Change the font size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-environments-font-size/57670804

You may be zoomed in though. Zoom out to show more.

Answer (score 1):

Using **ctrl + plus sign button or minus sign button**, you can easily change the font size. When you decrease font size (using **ctrl+-**), more lines would be displayable on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, you can zoom in / out by using the shortcuts **CTRL+** and **CTRL-**

This will affect the number of lines displayed.