# Visual Studio 2022: Increasing font of the app

Tags: visual-studio

Just to make everyone aware. My question is not about VS Code. My question is about Visual Studio 2022. Similar name, but two different products!

I am on Windows 10. Is there a way to increase the font of the Visual Studio 2022 app? I do know how to increase the font of the code (in the Visual Studio App) but I do not know how to increase the font of the app itself (font of the menu, side menu etc.)

[image]

I know how to increase the font of all the apps that I am using. This can be done in **Settings > System > Display.**
But that is not what I need. I want to scale one app only.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change environment's font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-environments-font-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022, simply go to the menu option `Tools`->`Options` Go to `Environment`->`Fonts and Colors`

Change the `Show settings for:` to **"Environment"**

Now change the Font and Font size, to the size of your choice.

Comment: This is a very good reply. Thank you so much. But it does not solve my problem.

I have changed the SHOW SETTINGS FOR to ENVIRONMENT and found the relevant font-size field. It is set to 9. But I am not allowed to change it. The field is grey. 

I am using the Community Edition. That might be the reason. What version are you using?

Comment: @DaliborPavlik You have to change the `Font` first, if it is set to `Automatic` you will not be able to change the `Size`. Change  `Font` to something like `Arial` and then Font size will be available.

Comment: Ok. It works. I have change the type of font and now the field has become white and I managed to change the size.

Thank you!!!