# In the VsCode, how to change the font size of the search bar only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The search bar in Visual Studio Code is rather small compared to the rest.

[image]

I wonder how to change only the search bar size. I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701933/how-to-change-environments-font-size) that we can use `"window.zoomLevel": 0` to change it. However, it changes all the environment (symbol size, window size, etc) and I want to change the search bar only.